# filter nested array of objects at multiple level and get back the matched objects in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter

I am looking to fix my current function which searches all possible matches and gives a whole nested array but it works for one level.

I am trying to use a filter and searching all properties through the loop.

Somehow it is not working for all scenarios.

```js
data = [
  {
    id: "m1",
    name: "data1",
    val: "D",
    items: [
      {
        id: "d1",
        name: "datanested1",
        val: "D",
        items: [
          {
            id: "1",
            name: "direct Data",
            val: "E"
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            name: "test",
            val: "E"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d2",
    name: "data2",
    val: "D",
    items: [
      {
        id: "21",
        name: "test21",
        val: "E"
      },
      {
        id: "22",
        name: "test23",
        val: "E"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d3",
    name: "data23",
    val: "D",
    items: [
      {
        id: "31",
        name: "test data 3",
        val: "E"
      },
      {
        id: "32",
        name: "test data 4",
        val: "E"
      }
    ]
  }
];
function getFilteredData(searchText) {
  return data.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(key => {
      return String(item[key])
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
    });
  });
}

console.log("data search level1", getFilteredData("data"));
//expected output
// [
//   {
//     id: "m1",
//     name: "data1",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "d1",
//         name: "datanested1",
//         val: "D",
//         items: [
//           {
//             id: "1",
//             name: "direct Data",
//             val: "E"
//           },
//           {
//             id: "2",
//             name: "B Data",
//             val: "E"
//           }
//         ]
//       }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     id: "d2",
//     name: "data2",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "21",
//         name: "test21",
//         val: "E"
//       },
//       {
//         id: "22",
//         name: "test23",
//         val: "E"
//       }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     id: "d3",
//     name: "data23",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "31",
//         name: "test data 3",
//         val: "E"
//       },
//       {
//         id: "32",
//         name: "test data 4",
//         val: "E"
//       }
//     ]
//   }
// ];
console.log("data search level2", getFilteredData("datanested1"));
//expected output
//  {
//     id: "m1",
//     name: "data1",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "d1",
//         name: "datanested1",
//         val: "D",
//         items: [
//           {
//             id: "1",
//             name: "direct Data",
//             val: "E"
//           },
//           {
//             id: "2",
//             name: "B Data",
//             val: "E"
//           }
//         ]
//       }
//     ]
//   }

console.log("data search level3", getFilteredData("direct"));
//expected output
//  {
//     id: "m1",
//     name: "data1",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "d1",
//         name: "datanested1",
//         val: "D",
//         items: [
//           {
//             id: "1",
//             name: "direct Data",
//             val: "E"
//           },
//         ]
//       }
//     ]
//   }

console.log("data search level2 common", getFilteredData("test"));
//expected output
// [
//   {
//     id: "d2",
//     name: "data2",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "21",
//         name: "test21",
//         val: "E"
//       },
//       {
//         id: "22",
//         name: "test23",
//         val: "E"
//       }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     id: "d3",
//     name: "data23",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "31",
//         name: "test data 3",
//         val: "E"
//       },
//       {
//         id: "32",
//         name: "test data 4",
//         val: "E"
//       }
//     ]
//   }
// ];
console.log("data search level1 common", getFilteredData("2"));

// [
//   {
//     id: "m1",
//     name: "data1",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "d1",
//         name: "datanested1",
//         val: "D",
//           {
//             id: "2",
//             name: "test",
//             val: "E"
//           }
//         ]
//       }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     id: "d2",
//     name: "data2",
//     val: "D",
//     items: [
//       {
//         id: "21",
//         name: "test21",
//         val: "E"
//       },
//       {
//         id: "22",
//         name: "test23",
//         val: "E"
//       }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     id: "d3",
//     name: "data23",
//     val: "D",
//       {
//         id: "32",
//         name: "test data 4",
//         val: "E"
//       }
//     ]
//   }
// ];
```

Below is stackblitz which I am trying.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1noseg

Comment: your wanted result is not clear. do you want the parent if nested items contains the wanted string? do you want to include the complete object if a parent continas the search string? why is in the result some items missing, like for `'test'`, node m1 is missing. by searching for `'2'`, node 32 is missing, because of the parent node ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a function which takes an array or later `items` and returns an array with either the objects which contains wanted value, or nothing.

```js
const
    getFilteredData = (array, value) => array.reduce((r, o) => {
        let { items = [], ...rest } = o,
            values = Object.values(rest);
        if (values.some(v => v.toString().includes(value))) {
            r.push(o);
        } else {
            items = getFilteredData(items, value);
            if (items.length) r.push({ ...o, items });
        }
        return r;
    }, []),
    data = [{ id: "m1", name: "data1", val: "D", items: [{ id: "d1", name: "datanested1", val: "D", items: [{ id: "1", name: "direct Data", val: "E" }, { id: "2", name: "test", val: "E" }] }] }, { id: "d2", name: "data2", val: "D", items: [{ id: "21", name: "test21", val: "E" }, { id: "22", name: "test23", val: "E" }] }, { id: "d3", name: "data23", val: "D", items: [{ id: "31", name: "test data 3", val: "E" }, { id: "32", name: "test data 4", val: "E" }] }],
    testdata = [{ id: "d3", name: "data23", val: "D", items: [ { id: "31", name: "b", val: "E" }, { id: "32", name: "c", val: "E" } ] }];

console.log("data", getFilteredData(data, "data"));
console.log("datanested1", getFilteredData(data, "datanested1"));
console.log("direct", getFilteredData(data, "direct"));
console.log("test", getFilteredData(data, "test"));
console.log("2", getFilteredData(data, "2"));
console.log("testdata", getFilteredData(testdata, "b"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: const testdata = [{
        id: "d3",
      name: "data23",
      val: null,
      items: [
        { id: "31", name: "b", val: "E" },
        { id: "32", name: "c", val: "E" }
      ]
}]
console.log("testdata", getFilteredData(testdata, "b"));

Comment: It is giving me both objects containing b and c

Comment: it took `items` property as well for checking. please see edit.